# Convert java bean with jxquery annotations to JSON string

Tags: java, json, converters, javabeans

How can I convert java bean, that was build using [jxQuery](https://code.google.com/p/jxquery/) annotations, back to JSON string?

For example i have bean with data:

```java
import com.googlecode.jxquery.jxQuery;

public class TestBean {

@jxQuery(query = "/client/can_use_day_budget")
private String canUseDayBudget;

@jxQuery(query =  "/validEmails/email")
private List<String> emails;

//getters and setters 
}
```

And I would like to get json string from it:

```
{ "validEmails":[{"email":"email1@gmail.com","select":""},{"email":"email2@gmail.com","select":""}],"client":{"can_use_day_budget":0}}
```

Thank you.